# Cannot find <GoogleToolboxForMac/GTMNSData+zlib.h> error when building an ionic project for ios

Tags: ionic-framework, cocoapods, google-toolbox-for-mac

I came across this error when trying to build an ionic project for ios. It happened in the FirebaseCore build part of the process.

I found the problem was a bug in the following file on line 23:

platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/Firebase/Core/FIRNetwork.m

It seems the angle brackets don't allow the search for the file to start at the Pods level, whereas quotes allow a relative path to be used.

I found the solution was to do the following, so I thought I'd post it here in case anyone else has the same problem:

Either:

Change line 23 from:

```
#import <GoogleToolboxForMac/GTMNSData+zlib.h>
```

to:

```
#import "../../../GoogleToolboxForMac/Foundation/GTMNSData+zlib.h"
```

Or:

Add the following to the end of the Header Search Paths setting your Xcode project Build Settings:

"${PODS_ROOT}"

Comment: that didn't work for me unfortunately. As I then had to chase down the rabbit hole to replace all #import <package/file.h> with the relative path equivalent, which is just too much to change. And "${PODS_ROOT}" is already set for m.  Did you ever find the root of the problem?

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm in the same situation as @JamesGilchrist. Did anyone find the root cause or another solution?

Comment: @JamesGilchrist, you could try adding ${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Private to the Header Search Paths setting too, as this is where all the header files reside.