# Unexpected errors in working app -> 'Private/FIRComponentContainerInternal.h' file not found

Tags: swift, firebase

A bunch of error cropped up unexpectedly in a working app tied to Firebase use.

'Private/FIRComponentContainerInternal.h' file not found
'GoogleToolboxForMac/GTMNSData+zlib.h' file not found

These reference calls are within the following files.

FIRNetwork.m

```
#import <GoogleToolboxForMac/GTMNSData+zlib.h>
```

FIRApp.m

```
#import "Private/FIRComponentContainerInternal.h"
```

I'm using the following with recent pod update:

```
XCODE 10 beta 4 (this is working)
Using BoringSSL (10.0.6)
Using Firebase (5.5.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (5.1.0)
Using FirebaseAuth (5.0.3)
Using FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
Using FirebaseCore (5.1.0)
Using FirebaseDatabase (5.0.2)
Using FirebaseFirestore (0.13.0)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (3.2.0)
Using FirebaseStorage (3.0.0)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.2.0)
Using GoogleAppMeasurement (5.1.0)
Using GoogleUtilities (5.2.2)
Using Layout (0.6.30)
Using Protobuf (3.6.1)
Using gRPC (1.14.1)
Using gRPC-Core (1.14.1)
Using gRPC-ProtoRPC (1.14.1)
Using gRPC-RxLibrary (1.14.1)
Using leveldb-library (1.20)
Using nanopb (0.3.8)
```

The fix may be related to Build Settings / Header Search Path as I've found issues related to this in the [past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216090/xcode-unit-testing-with-cocoapods/50205405#50205405).

My current Header Search Path:

```
$(inherited) ${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Firebase" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseAuthInterop"
```

Possibly related issue but the solutions don't solve my problem:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51636994/cannot-find-googletoolboxformac-gtmnsdatazlib-h-error-when-building-an-ionic
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an update from the Firebase team must have solve my issue because the app compiles successfully again with no strange missing file issues.

This is the versioning of SW after an update today.

```
Using BoringSSL (10.0.6)
Using Firebase (5.6.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (5.1.1)
Using FirebaseAuth (5.0.3)
Using FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
Using FirebaseCore (5.1.1)
Using FirebaseDatabase (5.0.2)
Using FirebaseFirestore (0.13.1)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (3.2.1)
Using FirebaseStorage (3.0.0)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.2.0)
Using GoogleAppMeasurement (5.1.1)
Using GoogleUtilities (5.2.2)
Using Layout (0.6.30)
Using Protobuf (3.6.1)
Using gRPC (1.14.1)
Using gRPC-Core (1.14.1)
Using gRPC-ProtoRPC (1.14.1)
Using gRPC-RxLibrary (1.14.1)
Using leveldb-library (1.20)
Using nanopb (0.3.8)
```

Note:

- Firebase 5.5.0 -> 5.6.0
- FirebaseCore 5.1.0 -> 5.1.1
- FirebaseFirestore 0.13.0 -> 0.13.1

All good.